# Sum all components and go to next

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, methods

I was thinking about my `code` and I think (after debbuging it) it doesnt work good.
In my task I have this short list of numbers:

```
numbers = [
        2892921,
        1939929,
        2929202,
        1758690,
```

I have to add to each other my numbers in this way:

> 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 2892921 = sum, and my `for loop` should go next: 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 1939929 = sum2 ect.

I've written this code. Please give me a sign where can I repeair it to work good?

```
def sum(__self__):
    suma = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(numbers):
        i += 1
        n = val
        for j in range(1, n):
            suma += j
        print(suma)
    return suma
```

Comment: why does this take ```__self__``` as an argument? also you shouldn't overwrite the builtin ```sum```

Comment: What does "doesn't work good" mean? Whats wrong with it?

Comment: @Sayse - It's becuase when I'm debuggin it it does not include last number of this list of numbers. That's why I think I  sould repair it

Comment: @VishalBalaji with this little correction it is ok, but still, my code remember last number. E.g: number: [10,100,1000] - 10: 55, and 100: should be: 5050, but it's 5050+55 and I don't want it.

Comment: Anyway guys, I'm grateful for your time. I'm at my very begginig I guess and I know that patience is the most important :) !

Comment: Ah okay. That's because you are not initialising `suma` in every loop. `suma=0` should be at the start of the first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numbers = [
        2892921,
        1939929,
        2929202,
        1758690
]
def sum_n(number):
  return sum(range(1, number+1))
sums = [sum_n(number) for number in numbers]

print(sums)
print(sum(sums))
```

Comment: Ok! I will try your code! Let me check it out! thanks

Answer (score 0):

just offering another alternative, using the proper formula

```
numbers = [
        2892921,
        1939929,
        2929202,
        1758690
]
def sum_n(number):
  return number*(number+1)/2
sums = [sum_n(number) for number in numbers]

print(sums)
print(sum(sums))
```

output:

```
[4184497402581.0, 1881663232485.0, 4290113643003.0, 1546496137395.0]
11902770415464.0
```

### Speed

this is actually about 14748x *faster* than the previous code, as my tests:

```
from timeit import timeit
numbers = [
        2892921,
        1939929,
        2929202,
        1758690
]
def sum_n(number):
  return number*(number+1)/2

def sum_n_old(number):
    return sum(range(1,number+1))

def create_sums():
    sums = [sum_n(number) for number in numbers]
    return sums,sum(sums)
def create_sums_old():
    sums = [sum_n_old(number) for number in numbers]
    return sums,sum(sums)


print("@XxJames07 method",new:=timeit(create_sums,number=10)*100,"ms")
print("@matszwecja method: ",old:=timeit(create_sums_old,number=10)*100,"ms")
print("XxJames method is",f"{old/new}x times faster")
```

output:

```
@XxJames07 method 0.03255000337958336 ms
@matszwecja method:  480.06977000040933 ms
XxJames method is 14748.685719078234x times faster
```

Comment: Did you use Python 2 for the first code and Python 3 for the second? This looks odd.

Comment: no but the second works only on python 3.10 because of the walrus operator

Comment: Then I see no explanation for your first output other than that that's not your true output...

Comment: it returned all float values instead of ints but i found unneccessary to specify i'll edit now

Comment: Hi, I don't and can't really understand if this code is going through each element? Like I wrote earlier: 1 + 2 + 3+ .... = sum of this number (and next)
This is very clever way to do this task but unfortunatley I have to do it step by step

Comment: It would be better to *not* use floats. You're at a size not that far away from where they become wrong.

Comment: @OP if you don't understand where the formula come from you can check out the wikipedia article about the [sum of the first n numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Comment: @KellyBundy we could transform the floats in integers by changing the "/" to "//" operator in the function

Comment: Yes, `//` is the right thing to do. Although it wouldn't "transform the floats". It would prevent floats to occur at all.